# Permission Denied while cloning a GitLab repository?

Tags: git, gitlab

I installed GitLab on my Ubuntu 18.04 as VM. I added my SSH key. When I try to clone

```
git clone git@192.168.50.10:johnholmes/helloworld2.git
Cloning into 'helloworld2'...
The authenticity of host '192.168.50.10 (192.168.50.10)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:f5ZhPsTYy3qV4aaRuct7ycOgB/CuC3MbD8QAgqYYp2A.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added '192.168.50.10' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
git@192.168.50.10's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
```

Or should I clone to `vagrant@gitlab:~$`

I want to clone empty repo,to add files and learn GitLab.

Comment: `ssh -Tv git@192.168.50.10`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not where you want to clone it. It's the access you have on the git server.

**Option 1 - Using Git GUI**

1. Go to Git GUI on your desktop -> Help -> Show SSH Key and copy the public Key (generate if not available)
2. Load the SSH public key to your Gitlab server. Go to Settings->SSH Keys and paste what you copied
3. Check that you have access to the repository you are trying to clone on Gitlab
4. Try again to clone

**Option 2 - only with command line**

1. Follow this guide https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Generating-Your-SSH-Public-Key to generate the SSH key and get your public Key
2. Follow Step 1-4 from Option 1

Comment: This is not helpful since the user is using `git`, not some GUI tool.

Comment: Git GUI comes by default with Git. You can use `git gui` on the command line to open it

Comment: Running `git gui` returns `git: 'gui' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.`; This must be some extension that you have installed.

Comment: You are right it seems is not always installed, depending on the system you are using (however, it can be installed in any system: Mac OS, Windows or Linux). I will update the answer to include a command-line approach too. Thanks for the feedback